# ArangoDB Example graph data is missing flights.csv

Tags: csv, arangodb

Following the ArangoDB "Graph Course for Freshers: The Shortest_Path  to first graph skills" requires flights.csv data to go along with airports.csv. Airports.csv is found at [GitHub - arangodb/example-datasets: Demo Data for ArangoDB](https://github.com/arangodb/example-datasets). However, I do not find flights.csv there (or anywhere else that turned up in a search).

Does anyone have a copy of it to share?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `airports.csv` file in the `example-dataset` repository (https://github.com/arangodb/example-datasets/blob/master/Airports/airports.csv) is a different file than is intended to be used for the Graph Course.

The right [Graph Course](https://www.arangodb.com/arangodb-graph-course/) files `airports.csv` and `flights.csv` can be downloaded via the link you find on page 15 of the PDF, with the headline *Download and Import the Dataset*:

[image: Screenshot of page 15]

The download link for the **2019 Edition** graph course dataset is:
https://www.arangodb.com/graphcourse_demodata_arangodb-2/

Comment: ...when attempts at collecting information for marketing get in the way of creating a good impression with the customer ...

Comment: Your answer did solve my problem. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I added the download link for the dataset and a screenshot of the page.